# Generating OSM map without HTML rendering but PDF rendering with iText?

Tags: openstreetmap, java, pdf

Is there a way to create an OSM map by a java bean, without displaying it in a web page, but instead stamping it inside a PDF which is generated with iText 5?

In my case, I want to generate kind of a serial letter as PDF, each copy containing a map, that displays a personal routing for the recipient.

So there is no need to show a map in a jsp or JSF page, only to create it and add it to the PDF.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this using the [GeoTools library](http://geotools.org), the [tile client module](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/extension/tile-client/tileclient.html) can render an OSM map. Then instead of calling the render to draw on a MapFrame's graphic you could use a `PdfGraphics2D` as the output instead. The tricky bit is setting the size you want.

```
DefaultFontMapper mapper = new DefaultFontMapper();
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

Graphics2D g2d = new PdfGraphics2D(cb, pageSize.getWidth(),
               pageSize.getHeight(), mapper ,rescale,rescale,0);
pageSize.setBorder(com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle.BOTTOM | com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle.TOP
      | com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle.LEFT | com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle.RIGHT);
  float dW = (float) (pageSize.getWidth() - canvasSize.getWidth());
  float dw2 = dW / 2.0f;
  pageSize.setBorderWidthLeft(dw2);
  pageSize.setBorderWidthRight(dw2);
  float dH = (float) (pageSize.getHeight() - canvasSize.getHeight());
  float dh2 = dH / 2.0f;
  pageSize.setBorderWidthBottom(dh2);
  pageSize.setBorderWidthTop(dh2);

  outputArea = new Rectangle((int) dw2, (int) dh2, canvasSize.width, canvasSize.height);
  ReferencedEnvelope dataArea = mapContent.getViewport().getBounds();
  mapPane.getRenderer().paint(g2d, outputArea, dataArea);
  g2d.dispose();
```